# Unable to render a state variable value in React Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to upload a file. There are some file validations performed on selecting a file.
Now, I want to display a message, like "validating file, please wait!" till the function (fileChange()) in the below code gets completed.

I don't see the message to be displayed, Can anyone please help me why is it happening ?

```
class FileUploaderComponent extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            validatingFile: false,
        }
    }

    fileChange = event => {
        this.setState({
            validatingFile: false,
        });
        if (event != undefined) {
            const inputFile = event.target.files[0];
            this.setState({
                validatingFile: true,
            });
            const fileReader = new FileReader();
            fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(inputFile);
            fileReader.onload = (e) => {
                const bufferArray = e.target.result;
                const wb = XLSX.read(bufferArray, { type: "buffer" });
                const wsname = wb.SheetNames[1];
                ... file validations
            };
        }
        this.setState({
            validatingFile: false,
        });
    }



    render() {        
        return (
            <div>
                <h2 className='common-text'>Upload your file below:</h2>
                <input 
                    className='input-block' 
                    type="file" 
                    onChange={this.fileChange} 
                    accept="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" 
                />
                {this.state.validatingFile ? <h6 className='common-text'> Validating File. Please wait!</h6> : ""}
                
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the final call to set state inside the `onload` callback:

```
fileReader.onload = (e) => {
  const bufferArray = e.target.result;
  const wb = XLSX.read(bufferArray, { type: "buffer" });
  const wsname = wb.SheetNames[1];
        
  ... file validations
        
  this.setState({
      validatingFile: false,
  });
};
```

The `onload` callback is triggered asynchronously after the file has finished loading. In your current code sample, the call to set state back to `false` happens before it has processed the data. Since multiple successive state calls are batched, the effect is essentially that no change occurs, even though you set state to `true` previously.